# Snowflake week and year

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to extract year and week from date format and create output column like YYYY-WK. I understand that we shall do it using YEAR(date)||WEEK(DATE) function.

But, my use case is that the week should start on Friday and not Sunday(default). I need to achieve this using SELECT query and do not have options for alter session/write procedure.

Is there a way to achieve this in Snowflake SQL please? Thanks.

Example: 2023-12-29 should be 2023-51 and
2023-12-31 should give 2024-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Snowflake defaults to starting day of the week on Sunday, the easiest way to get your results is to "shift" the date ahead by 2 days (Friday to Sunday).

```sql
WITH T0(THE_DATE) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('2023-12-29'::DATE),
    ('2023-12-31'::DATE)
)
SELECT
    THE_DATE,
    DATEADD(DAY, 2, THE_DATE) DATE_SHIFTED,
    YEAR(DATE_SHIFTED) THE_YEAR,
    WEEK(DATE_SHIFTED) THE_WEEK,
    CONCAT(THE_YEAR, '-', RIGHT('0' || THE_WEEK, 2)) AS YEAR_WEEK
FROM T0;
```

| THE_DATE | DATE_SHIFTED | THE_YEAR | THE_WEEK | YEAR_WEEK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-29 | 2023-12-31 | 2023 | 52 | 2023-52 |
| 2023-12-31 | 2024-01-02 | 2024 | 1 | 2024-01 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    TO_VARIANT(
        DATE_TRUNC('WK', DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAYOFWEEK_FRIDAY, YOUR_DATE_COLUMN))
    ) AS YearWeek
FROM
    YourTableName;
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, what is DAYOFWEEK_FRIDAY used for please?